# Update Data from Child component - Vue.js/Axios/Laravel

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to update data that comes from a child component on a Vue.js Laravel application and for some reason, i cant that straight to work. The return given on the inspector tells me

> Creating default object from empty value

The parent component opens a modal which is a child component, then the information has to be updated through the update() method. Can someone help me understand what I'm missing?

This is basically a img of my database for a matter of knowing how it is structured:

[image]

Those methods are in my parent component Log.vue and this is how i am passing the data from the parent to the child component:

```
<log-edit v-if="editModalOpen" :logId="logId" :logUser="logUser" :logTitle="logTitle" :logType="logType" :logDescription="logDescription" :logDate="logDate" @closeRequest='close'></log-edit>

<td @click="openEdit(log.id,log.user,log.title,log.type,log.description,log.created_at)"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></td>
<script>


methods:{
 openEdit(id,user,title,type,description,date){
                    this.logId = id;
                    this.logUser = user;
                    this.logTitle = title;
                    this.logType = type;
                    this.logDescription = description;
                    this.logDate = date;
                    this.editModalOpen = true;
                },
}

<script>
```

This is the EditLog.vue which is the child component receiving the data from the parent above:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="overlay">
            <div class="edit-detail-window">
                <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">{{logTitle}}</h3>
                        <button type="button" class="close">
                        <i class="fas fa-times" @click="close"></i>
                        </button>
                </div>
                <div id="show-detail-modal-body" class="modal-body">
                    <br>
                    <label>Title:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="logTitle">

                    <br>
                    <label>Type:</label>
                    <select v-model="logType" class="form-control" ><br>
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
                                <option>Client Update</option>
                                <option>Dev Update</option>
                                <option>Bug</option>
                                <option>Style Fix</option>
                    </select>

                    <br>
                    <label>Description:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5" v-model="logDescription"></textarea>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button d="log-it" type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-xl" @click="update(logTitle, logType, logDescription)">
                        <span><b>EDIT</b></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>

import axios from 'axios';

export default {

    name:'EditLog',

    props:['logId','logUser','logTitle','logType','logDescription','logDate'],

    data(){
        return{
            log:{title:'',type:'',description:''},
            errors:{}
        }
    },

    methods:{

        close(){
            this.$emit('closeRequest');
        },

        update(title,type,description){

            this.log.title = title;
            this.log.type = type;
            this.log.description - description;

            window.axios.patch(`/develogger-app/public/api/logs/${this.logId}`,this.$data.log).then((response)=> this.close())
                    .catch((error) => this.errors = error.response.data.errors)

        }

    }
}
</script>
```

This is the Log routes/api.php

```
Route::patch('/logs/{id}','LogController@update');
```

This is the update function on LogController.php

```
public function update($id, Request $request){

        $log = Log::find($request->id);
        $log->title = $request->logTitle;
        $log->type = $request->logType;
        $log->description = $request->logDescription;

        $log->save();

    }
```

Any clue on how to make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few of points I noticed here that perhaps were too big for a comment.

Firstly, Instead of passing all the seperate properties of a `log` through to the `<edit-log>` component, it might be easier just to pass the whole object in?

```
<edit-log :log="log"></edit-log>
```

Secondly, it doesn't look like you are binding the prop data you are sending in to `<edit-log>` to the `data` on that component.  I don't think you can v-model directly to a prop.

Thirdly, I think where you are doing the update in the `<edit-log>` component, you just need to pass the data in like `this.log` instead of `this.$data.log`.

So your `<edit-log>` might look like this in full

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="overlay">
            <div class="edit-detail-window">
                <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">{{logTitle}}</h3>
                        <button type="button" class="close">
                        <i class="fas fa-times" @click="close"></i>
                        </button>
                </div>
                <div id="show-detail-modal-body" class="modal-body">
                    <br>
                    <label>Title:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="log.title">

                    <br>
                    <label>Type:</label>
                    <select v-model="log.type" class="form-control" ><br>
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
                                <option>Client Update</option>
                                <option>Dev Update</option>
                                <option>Bug</option>
                                <option>Style Fix</option>
                    </select>

                    <br>
                    <label>Description:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5" v-model="log.description"></textarea>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button d="log-it" type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-xl" @click="update()">
                        <span><b>EDIT</b></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>

import axios from 'axios';

export default {

    name:'EditLog',

    props:['initiaLog'],

    data(){
        return{
            log:this.initialLog,
            errors:{}
        }
    },

    methods:{

        close(){
            this.$emit('closeRequest');
        },

        update(){

            window.axios.patch(`/develogger-app/public/api/logs/${this.logId}`,this.log)
                .then((response)=> this.close())
                .catch((error) => this.errors = error.response.data.errors)

        }

    }
}
</script>
```

and you would call initialise it like this

```
<log-edit v-if="editModalOpen" :initial-log="log" @closeRequest='close'></log-edit>
```